# Create measure for % of Sales in Power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a % of sales measure in power bi. I currently have a visual that is filtered on sales for select items by day and another visual that just has the total sales by day and then I export and do the math in excel. I know there is a way to have just one visual give me the % of sales for the items I have selected, but can't figure out the DAX formula. I am looking for the formula that will take sales for item 1 on Monday of $3,461 and divide by total sales for Monday of $163,534 to get a 2.1% of sales (for all items). Thanks

[Power Bi Visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeaDh.png)

I tried a couple formulas but was unsuccessful..

Answer (score 0):

The December release of PBI has been pushed out to all users, and it comes with a brand-new WINDOW function. This allows you to create calculations that would be relative to data being displayed in the visualization rather than applying across an entire table.

Some things you can do with this type of DAX calculation:

- Moving averages
- Can also combine with parameters for additional functionality!
- Dynamic reference lines
- Cross row calculations
- Finding best and worst performers (with ABS references)
- **Calculate contributions to the whole**

Relevant links:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eib5X5xRlz8
2. [Introducing DAX Window Functions (Part 1) – pbidax (wordpress.com)](https://pbidax.wordpress.com/2022/12/15/introducing-dax-window-functions-part-1/)
3. [WINDOW – DAX Guide](https://dax.guide/window/)